# How to test a VueJS (Nuxt) Store in Jest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I have a Jest test that is testing my VueJs component (specifically Nuxt, but not important for this). I am attempting to mock a store that is an JSON Object. I for the life of me can not figure out how to test this. The error I keep getting when I run my test is "Cannot read propery 'easg_logo' of undefined".

My Vue component (footer.vue)

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <v-img 
         :height="easg_logo_height"
         :src="$store.state.app.easg_logo.src"
         :width="easg_logo_width"
        contain
         />
     <v-img 
         :height="oma_logo_height"
         :src="$store.state.app.oma_logo.src"
         :width="oma_logo_width"
        contain
         />
       </div>
    </template>
<script>
   export default {
      data(){
         easg_logo_width: this.$store.state.app.easg_logo.top.width, 
         easg_logo_height: this.$store.state.app.easg_logo.top.height,
         oma_logo_width: this.$store.state.app.oma_logo.top.width,
         oma_logo_width: this.$store.state.app.oma_logo.top.width,
      }
   }
</script>
```

My test (footer.test.js)

```
import {shallowMount, createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Footer from '@components/layouts/default/footer'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

const vuetify = new Vuetify();
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe("Footer tests", ()=> {
  let wrapper;
  let store;
  let state;


beforeEach(() => {
   state= {
     app: {
        easg_logo:{
           src: "~/assets/images/easg.jpg",
           text: "EASG", 
           top:{
             height: 72,
             width: 82
           }
         },
    oma_logo:{
           src: "~/assets/images/oma.jpg",
           text: "OMA", 
           top:{
             height: 72,
             width: 82
           }
         }
      }
}

store = new Vuex.Store({
            modules:{
               state
            }
     })

})

test('store test', ()=> {
   wrapper = shallowMount(Footer, {store, localVue, vuetify})
   console.log(wrapper)
   const a = 'a'
    expect(a).toBe('a')
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no state because `state` was mistakenly provided as a module.

It should be:

```
 store = new Vuex.Store({
   state
 })
```